# const char* fails to check for null or empty or "" in if-statement

Tags: c++

I am using [replxx](https://github.com/AmokHuginnsson/replxx) and I try to receive input from it as follows:

```
replxx::Replxx m_repl;
m_repl.input("> ");
```

It returns me a `const char*`, and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the console terminal without typing anything else, it says `"" 0 \000`, but the strangest thing is, performing an `if` check like this doesn't work:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  replxx::Replxx repl;
  for(;;){
      auto line = repl.input("> ");
      if(line == "")
         continue;
      // Otherwise process. 
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: I tried,**

- `if(line == '\0')`
- `if(line == '\0' || line == ' ')`

Comment: You can't compare C strings with `line == ""`. The compiler should also be warning you about that. Checking a pointer to be a null pointer is `line == nullptr`. Comparing C strings is done with `strcmp`.

Comment: @user17732522, guessing there is a bug then.

Comment: For C string comparisons, [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: You can always build a C++ `std::string` from a null terminated (const) char array (aka a C-string). From that point you will be able to use all the C++ string goodies: `std::string line(repl.input("> ");` and `if (line.empty()) ...`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if the string is empty, the most direct way would be:

```cpp
if (line[0] == '\0')
  continue;
```

However, it is easier to use a C++ string type, like `std::string_view`, where you can just use `==`:

```cpp
std::string_view line = repl.input("> ");
if (line == "")
   continue;
```

Comment: `if (line.empty())` would be better than `if (line == "")`

Comment: @RemyLebeau the OP seems new to C++. The intuitive syntax is more readable to her. The plus side of this answer is no-copy and no-allocation design.

Comment: @Red.Wave, I am NOT **NEW** to C++. I haven't used the language for a long-time. Big difference.

Comment: @Red.Wave, not up to you to decide. You barely know me.